# Warning: comparison between pointer and integer, assignment make integer from pointer without a cast?

Tags: c

I'm getting these warnings right now and I'm not sure why. I've put the warning message in the code next to the line it corresponds with.

```
void removeNewLine (char * userName, int charLenght)
{
int i=0; 

do {
    if (userName [i]=='/n') //comparison between pointer and integer
    {
        userName [i]='/0'; //assignment makes integer from pointer w/o cast
    }
i++;
} while (i<charLenght);

}
```

Comment: Don't put a space between the array name and the subscript: `userName[i] == '\n'` etc. (especially when you don't put spaces around the binary operator `==`). You've been told, correctly, about the misuse of slash vs backslash. However, the error messages make no sense to me. While the notation `'/n'` is not portable (GCC says `warning: multi-character character constant`), it generates an integer value, not a pointer value. Are you sure you copied and pasted your code accurately? Also, it's unusual to need to zap every newline with a null byte; usually, the first is sufficient (add `break;`).

Comment: The error messages are consistent with `userName[i] = "/0";` and `username[i] == "/n"`, of course.

Answer (score 5):

You have the wrong slash. You want `'\n'` for newline and `'\0'` for NULL character.